# PreferenceActivity динамическое формирование экрана настроек

Tags: android, activity, android-preferences, android-shared-preferences

На скорую руку сделал такой вариант динамически формируемого экрана с настройками

```
onCreate(....{
 EditTextPreference[] etprefArr = new EditTextPreference[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < etprefArr.length; i++) {
        etprefArr[i] = new EditTextPreference(this);
        etprefArr[i].setKey("etpOwner" + i);
        etprefArr[i].setTitle(preference.getString("etpOwner" + i, null));
        etprefArr[i].setIcon(R.drawable.telephone_1_32);
        ownerScreen.addPreference(etprefArr[i]);
        if (etprefArr[i].getTitle()==null ||etprefArr[i].getTitle().equals("")){
            break;
        }
    }
```

Работает создание `EditTextPreference` как и задумывалось (если имеющийся `EditTextPreference` заполнен, появляется новый, только вопрос в том, что `PreferenceScreen` содержащий данные `EditTextPreference`  обновляется только после пересоздания `PreferenceActivity`.

Подскажите, как правильно динамически формировать `PreferenceScreen`.
Была мысль создать свой класс раширяющий `PreferenceScreen` или `EditTextPreference`.
Возможно есть более правильные/простые решения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текущая версия экрана выглядит так:
`PreferenceScreen` на него добавлен "статичный" `EditTextPreference` "Добавить".
При клике на него появляется стандартный диалог, ввожу новое значение и при сохранении сохраняю значение в новый в Preference под своим "именем+(count+1).  В итоге новое значение добавлено, но не отображено на `PreferenceScreen`.
И так для каждый раз при нажатии "Добавить".

При следующем входе на данный `PreferenceScreen`  перебирают все Preference  "именем+(count+1,2,3...)" . получаю экран со значениями, но при их корректировки, на экране отображаются старые значения

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13403122/3212712) говорят, что надо так:

```
setPreferenceScreen(null);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, пока не сообразил как данный вариант применить. Если у меня  `PreferenceActivity` формируется динамически и `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);` не используется пока попробовал  вариант `.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newVal) {
      
            return true;
        }

    });` работает, но на каждый компонент добавлять,много кода получается. наверно не очень правильно.

Comment: Добрый день! так и не смог разобраться, как обновить PreferenceScreen, если у меня полностью все настройки формируются динамически и не используются ресурсы.

Comment: @x555xx, что-то мне с ходу не понять что именно у вас не работает и как должно, но попробуйте повесить слушатели изменения настроек и в их колбэке что-то сделать.

Comment: немногого переоформил текст в топике, думаю стало понятней